# File Move operation fails due to special characters

Tags: c#, .net, file, special-characters, move

I have a file move operation and the folder path has special characters like [,(,~ and also some file names which has those special characters. I read the file path and the name from a .csv file.  Now I would like those files to be moved and when I try to move through c# I get illegal characters in path error. How do I get past that error and move the files?

```
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    char[] delimiters = new char[] { ',' };
    parts= line.Split(delimiters);
    if (parts.Length > 0)
    {
        SourceFilePathCSV = parts[0];
        SourceFileNameCSV = parts[1];
        filesize = parts[2];

        totalSourceFilePath = Path.Combine(SourceFilePathCSV ,SourceFileNameCSV);
        strDestinationDynamicPath = SourceFilePathCSV.Replace("\\\server\folder\\", " ").TrimEnd();
        strConstructedDestinationfullpath = Path.Combine(strDestinationStaticPath, strDestinationDynamicPath);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strConstructedDestinationfullpath)) 
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(strDestinationDynamicPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(strConstructedDestinationfullpath);
                try
                {
                    if (File.Exists(totalSourceFilePath))
                    {
                        strtotaldestinationpath = Path.Combine(strConstructedDestinationfullpath, SourceFileNameCSV);
                        File.Move(totalSourceFilePath, strtotaldestinationpath);
                        string changed = Path.ChangeExtension(totalSourceFilePath, ".txt");
                        File.WriteAllText(changed, strTextInsidefile);
                        logMessage = "SourceFile = " + totalSourceFilePath + " DestinationFile = " + strConstructedDestinationfullpath + "  " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "   " + loggeduserid.ToString() + " Input file = " + inputfile + "  " + "  Moved + " + "filesize = " + filesize;
                        WriteLog(logMessage);
                        filecountMoved = filecountMoved + 1;

                    }//file.exists(totalsource)
                    else
                    {
                        filecountnotmoved = filecountnotmoved + 1;
                        logMessage = "SourceFile = " + totalSourceFilePath + " DestinationFile = " + strConstructedDestinationfullpath + "  " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "   " + loggeduserid.ToString() + " Input file = " + inputfile + "  " + "Not Moved " + "filesize = " + filesize;
                        WriteLog(logMessage);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    string strlogmessageex = ex.Message.ToString();
                    WriteLog(strlogmessageex);
                    return;
                }
                }//if directory not exists

        }//string or null
    }//parts.length
    filecount = filecount + 1;
}//while
```

Comment: Have You tried to create those folders manually in Your operating system? I think You can't do that. It's an OS restriction rather than programming problem.

Comment: Those are not invalid characters for a file.  Are you sure the issue isn't with some other characters?  Can you show the exact file name it fails on?

Comment: @ntohl, These folders are not manually created and all my program do is to move certain files in folders to a different location. I agree , am not sure how the folders/files were allowed to create with special characters too.

Comment: @juharr, this is a file it fails on \\server\share\legal\xxxxxxx,xxxx\x.docs from CS (Recd Dec 2014)\OPCC\CS's office\DLS acct.Forms\KLtrReTransferToTrust(062323).doc. In this, the path/folder name is   \\server\share\legal\xxxxxxx,xxxx\x.docs from CS (Recd Dec 2014)\OPCC\CS's office\DLS acct.Forms\  and the file name is KLtrReTransferToTrust(062323).doc

Answer (score 1):

You can programatically remove invalid characters from a string using the collection returned from [`Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getinvalidfilenamechars)

However, if the files do actually exist, then you must be introducing invalid characters. Unless it's a copy/paste error, it might be this line:

```
strDestinationDynamicPath = SourceFilePathCSV.Replace("\\\server\folder\\", " ").TrimEnd();
```

You have three slashes at the start. "\\" is one character and "\s" is another. But that might be a copy/paste error.

But then you're replacing that with a space, which is an invalid character for the first character of a file or folder. `TrimEnd` only removes spaces at the end.

If it's not that, then debug and look at the value of `strConstructedDestinationfullpath` and look for anything odd.

Comment: you are right, \\\ is a copy paste error. I am able to move files with no special characters it only fails if a folder/file name contains '(,{,~,[' etc